# Cant find a locator for a link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class HomePage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage() {
        System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        PageFactory.initElements (driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='MenuContent']/a[2]")
    WebElement signInButton;


    public void signInButtonClick() {
        signInButton.click();

    }
}
```

and this is the main method:

```
import Pages.HomePage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        driver.manage ().timeouts ().implicitlyWait (10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage ().window ().maximize ();
        driver.get ("https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action");

        HomePage homePage = new HomePage ();
        homePage.signInButtonClick ();
    }
}
```

i am trying to get a locator (CSS or XPATH or really anything by this point) for a specific link and i cant manage no matter what I try.

this is the link in question:

`<a href="/actions/Account.action;jsessionid=502B0A6FB872ED0C4A8C94A6467A0C96?signonForm=">Sign In</a>`

I have tried to find locators for `a[text()='Sign In']`

after I run the main method the process does not execute and this are the errors:

```
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='MenuContent']/a[2]}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy4.click(Unknown Source)
    at Pages.HomePage.signInButtonClick(HomePage.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

- There are few things incorrect here.
  Driver is getting initialized 2 times which should not be correct.
  Path to geckodriver seems incorrect as well.

I am adding the correct code below but have used chromedriver instead of geckodriver. It is working with the below code.

```
package sample;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class HomePage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage() {
        System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/riteshpc/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Drivers/chromedriver");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements (driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Sign In']")
    WebElement signInButton;


    public void signInButtonClick() {
        signInButton.click();
    }
}
```

```
package sample;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage();
        WebDriver driver = homePage.driver;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait (10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action");
    
        homePage.signInButtonClick();
    }
}
```

To copy your driver location, you can simply go to the driver's folder location in your eclipse and right click the driver and from properties you can copy path.
I have added the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: i switched to chrome driver and still doesnt work with your code :(

Comment: what error you are getting? Could you please share your driver path as well because I think the problem could be because of that. Also are you sure that the versions you are using for your selenium and driver are compatible with each other?

Comment: I am using Selenium - 3.141.59, and chromeDriver is of the latest version.

Comment: same here, I am now editing to the Updated code used please take a look :)

Comment: In your code, in Main class you are initially creating an instance of the WebDriver. Now on the 2nd last line when you create HomePage object, you would be creating another instance of the WebDriver, and since you are using HomePage instance to click on the SignIn button. And if you remember the petStore url was opened using the other instance of the driver. That's why it couldn't find the SignIn button.

Comment: In the main class, create instance of HomePage on the first line and use homepage.driver (like I did). And use that driver to perform the remaining operations. Update you Main class code to the code I had written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need to be corrected.

1. You are creating 2 drivers, one in `main` and one in `HomePage`. You should create driver from your `main` and pass that instance into `HomePage` through the constructor.
2. Your first XPath, as you posted it, is not valid. `a[text()='Sign In']` should be `//a[text()='Sign In']`.
3. The creator of Selenium has stated that `PageFactory` and implicit waits are a bad practice and should not be used. Instead use the Page Object Model and `WebDriverWait`.

I rewritten your code and tested it and it successfully clicks the Sign In link.

Main.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import Pages.HomePage;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action");

        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        homePage.signInButtonClick();
    }
}
```

HomePage.java

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class HomePage {
    WebDriver driver;

    private By signInButton = By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign In']");

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void signInButtonClick() {
        driver.findElement(signInButton).click();
    }
}
```